# Wix Installer and XSLT - Omitting of certain files in specific directory

Tags: .net, xslt, wix, installation, wix3.5

I am following the steps given in the below link to create the installer. And I am new to Wix Installer.

[Creating WIX Installer using DotNet](http://utopianconcept.com/posts/creating-a-wix-installer-for-a-.net-web-project/)

Using steps given by the above article I am able to create Wix project and it is working fine aswell.

Here I am using Xsl to control the files which i don't want to include.

```
<xsl:key name="xml-search" match=" wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.xml')]" use ="@Id " />
<!--Match and ignore leftover .xml files on developer machines -->  
<xsl:template match=" wix:Component[key('xml-search', @Id)]" />  
<xsl:template match=" wix:ComponentRef[key('xml-search', @Id)]" />
```

I am Creating WIX Installer for dotNet web application.So I am publishing the application and assigning the path to .Wixproj.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<HeatDirectory NoLogo="$(HarvestDirectoryNoLogo)"
SuppressAllWarnings="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressAllWarnings)"
SuppressSpecificWarnings="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressSpecificWarnings);"
ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)"
TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(HarvestDirectoryTreatWarningsAsErrors)"
TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors="$(HarvestDirectoryTreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors)"
VerboseOutput="$(HarvestDirectoryVerboseOutput)" AutogenerateGuids="false"
GenerateGuidsNow="true" OutputFile="Components.wxs"
SuppressFragments="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressFragments)"
SuppressUniqueIds="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressUniqueIds)"
Directory="D:\wixTest\Custom\WebApplication" ComponentGroupName="C_CommonAssemblies"
Transforms="WIXInstaller.xslt" DirectoryRefId="TARGETDIR" KeepEmptyDirectories="false" 
PreprocessorVariable="var.SourceDir" SuppressCom="%(HarvestDirectory.SuppressCom)"
SuppressRootDirectory="true" SuppressRegistry="%(HarvestDirectory.SuppressRegistry)">
</HeatDirectory>
```

The Problem is it is removing all .XML files which are in the project directory. I want to remove only from specific directory (\bin). is that possible ? If Yes, Guide Me..

Comment: There is a whitespace in `<xsl:key name= " xml-search"...`. Typo?

Comment: @MathiasMüller . Yes,That is a typo....

Comment: It is possible to refine your templates. But first you need to tell us how the directory info is encoded in XML. That is, how do you know if a certain XML file is in `\bin`? Is it part of the `@Source`?

Comment: Thanks, but it does not really answer my question. You have to show an XMl that contains `wix:File` elements with Source attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still unclear how you know which files are in the `bin` folder, but I'll give it a try.

In case the `Source` attributes contains a full file path:

```
<xsl:key name="xml-search" match=" wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.xml') and contains(wix:File/@Source,'\bin')]" use ="@Id " />
```